# How do I filter queries in GraphQL with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and am currently trying to implement it in my nodejs project with mongodb as my database(using mongoose). I have my schema set up as well as resolvers that handle communicating with the database and it is all working fine. Using the graphiql tool I can make queries and mutations and everything is persisting to the database perfectly. I am now trying to implement filtering and sorting to the GraphQL API but I'm getting confused. I understand that I can pass arguments to my queries and then access those in my resolvers and write the logic to put those in my mongodb queries. But I am finding myself having to define an input in my GraphQL schema for every possible filter that can be applied. For example, a portion of my schema allows me to filter products by their price:

```
type Product {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    price: Float!
}

input ProductFilterInput {
    price: IntFilter
}

input IntFilter {
    eq: Float
    gt: Float
    gte: Float
    lt: Float
    lte: Float
    between: [Float]
}

type RootQuery {
    products(filters: ProductFilterInput): [Product]
}
```

Then in my resolver, I have to handle each possible filter argument differently. If the query argument was "{price: {gt: 10}}", I have to say something like

"Product.find({price: {$gt: 10}})".

Writing a bunch of different checks and logic in the resolver for each possible filter seems crazy to me. When I research this, I can find resources on using arguments to filter the GraphQL queries themselves, but I'm struggling to find documentation on how to write the schemas and resolvers. Maybe I'm overlooking something, but is there a way to write the schemas and resolvers in such a way that I don't have to explicitly define each filter and then again explicitly translate each filter in the resolver? Perhaps a way to write the resolver so I can simply plug the argument into the mongoose "find" method and it understands what I am asking?

Hopefully that all made sense, if you would like me to try to explain further, I can do my best.

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: follow some better, more universal [API] condition building pattern/examples ... sth like `where: {field: "price", condition: "gt", value: 10}`, and/or 'operators', tree structured, parsable, convertable to your DB/service requirements

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes way more sense than what I was trying to do. And it makes writing the schema and resolvers much simpler!